# Trouble accessing a struct member from a void pointer.

Tags: c, struct, void-pointers

I am not too experienced in C and I am having trouble with something that might be simple you for most of you. Basically, I have this structure that defines a 'generic' queue with a resizing array implementation:

```
typedef void (*free_fptr)(void *);

typedef struct {
    void **queue;       // pointer to generic type
    size_t first;       // head index in array
    size_t last;        // tail index in array
    size_t size;        // number of elements
    size_t capacity;    // capacity of array
    size_t elem_size;   // size in bytes of each element in queue
    free_fptr deleter;  // function used to free each element
} Queue;
```

Now, I have a data type that I want to put in the queue :

```
typedef struct {
    Process_state state;
    Queue time_queue;
    unsigned int start_time;
    unsigned int id;
} Process;
```

I also have a function 'Queue_destroy(Queue *q)' that I want to call when I need to free each element in the queue :

```
void
Queue_destroy(Queue *q)
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < q->size; ++i) {
        q->deleter(q->queue[(q->first + i) % q->capacity]);
    }

    free(q->queue);
```

}

Now, my problem is that I don't know to access to the 'Process' queue inside the queue from a void pointer. For example :

```
void
Process_deleter(void *item)
{   
    // Here I want to access the queue inside (Process *)item
    free((Process *)item);
}
```

I tried many things without success such as :

```
    Queue_destroy((*(Process *)item).time_queue);
    Queue_destroy((Process *)item->time_queue);
```

It does not compile and I am clueless!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You snippets of the code are lacking information, it is a mess. Present a simple compilable example instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function:

```
Queue_destroy(Queue *q)
```

expects a `Queue*`

So, change:

```
Queue_destroy((*(Process *)item).time_queue); // Here you are passing the object
```

to:

```
Queue_destroy(&(((Process *)item)->time_queue));
```

Assuming `item` is a pointer to your `struct Process`

Comment: i get the same error as i did: simfb.c:188:33: error: request for member ‘time_queue’ in something not a structure or union

Comment: How are you calling `Process_deleter()` ?

Comment: In my answer I am assuming that you have called the function with right arguments. You need to show that too. Also, how are you creating objects/pointers of the struct?

Comment: nevermind it is working now! thanks you made me understand it! ;)